# Determine if event is static using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, static, memberinfo

I have a `System.Reflection.EventInfo` object, and I want to know whether the event described by this object is static or not. Unlike `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`, `EventInfo` does not have `IsStatic` property that would tell me what I need. So, how can I do it in C#?

Also, if I have a `MemberInfo` object that describes some member of my class (could be property, method, field, etc.), how can I determine if this member is static or not? Is the only way to do it to cast my `MemberInfo` object into the needed type (into `MethodInfo` if this was a method, for example) and then check if this member is static?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `Event`, when declared, under the hood turns into a special method typed as a `delegate` with an `Add` and `Remove` methods.

What you can do, is check the `Add` method being generated to see if it is `static`:

```
var isStaticEvent = eventInfo.GetAddMethod().IsStatic;
```

Comment: Thanks. And what about the determining whether MemberInfo is static? Can I determine it only after I cast MemberInfo into MethodInfo, CosntructorInfo, or whatever the member type is?

Comment: @user Yes, you must cast